# No module named __future__ using python embedded in C++

Tags: python, c++, anaconda

I'm calling a python function from a CPP file using Visual Studio.  My default python environment is Anaconda 5.3.0.  When I run the .py file itself in the Anaconda prompt it works.  But when I try to call the function by embedding it in the CPP file, I get the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__future__'
```

The future file is indeed in my anaconda environment and it works in the anaconda prompt.  But for some reason it doesn't work when embedded into C++ and ran through Visual Studio even with my default python environment set to Anaconda.

This is the following code for my CPP file.

```
// Initialize the Python interpreter.
Py_Initialize();

PySys_SetPath(L"filepath");

// Convert the file name to a Python string.
PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_FromString("filename");
// Import the module
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
if (pModule) {
    //do stuff
}
else {
    PyErr_Print();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you use `PySys_SetPath`?

Comment: The filepath to my python file was in a different directory than the directory of my CPP file